# How much current needed to power arduino uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, voltage

I am planning to build an rc car based on arduino uno. I will use 3S 11.1 V Li-po to power whole circuitry. So my question is;

First, can arduino be powered directly with 11.1V from its Vin pin? Would it be a problem or not? If it is OK, then no need to answer the bold part below.

**If it is not, then one solution comes to my mind is to use a voltage regulator which will convert 11.1 V to 5 V. But while choosing a regulator, I saw that max output current is one of the important specs. So what is the minimum amount of current needed to run Arduino UNO?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum voltage at the Vin pin is 12V, so using your battery is fine!

Considering the current consumption:
The arduino itself will usually source less than 200mA, but your whole setup will probably sink more than that.

Comment: I was wondering just because of the current limitation of voltage regulator, I would use it only to power arduino. For exampe there was one with max 600mA output current so in that case, if 11.1 V wasn't be a valid input, then 600mA is also capable of supplying arduino based on what I understood from your answer. Thanks!